# Weirdest java issue I've encountered, NoClassDefFoundError due to an Annotation?

Tags: java, android, annotations, noclassdeffounderror

I think I hit something rough... let me know your thoughts.

I've been developing for while now an infra project for **Android** which uses **Annotations**, which I use to define a couple of things.

Take a look at the following annotation, it should compile, and it does, but when I run it on the device, I get a NoClassDefFoundException.

```
@Target({FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ViewIdentifier {

    int viewId() default -1;

    int[] viewIds() default {};

    ViewUI_Action[] listeners() default {};

    boolean forDev() default false;

}
```

This is **THE** implementation:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@ViewIdentifier(
        listeners = ViewUI_Action.OnClickAsCollection,
        viewIds = {R.id.AccelerometerEngineeringScreen, R.id.RotationVectorEngineeringScreen, R.id.NetworkEngineeringScreen,
                R.id.MagneticEngineeringScreen, R.id.OrientationEngineeringScreen, R.id.GPS_EngineeringScreen, R.id.CallsEngineeringScreen,
                R.id.UpgradeAppButton, R.id.DEV_Action_Button, R.id.FYI_Button})
private View[] modelViews;
```

If I remove the *ViewIdentifier* Annotation, the code compiles, and runs fine, the app starts, but if I return the annotation, the NoClassDefFoundError persists.

This is NOT a clean build issue, I've been very careful before posting this, plus, The missing class file is in the bin/classes, and it does work regardless of clean build when I remove the annotation. I've tried refreshing the workspace rebuilding it, close-open project, restart Eclipse, and other tricks.

The weirdest thing is that if I reverse the parameter of the annotation eg.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@ViewIdentifier(
        viewIds = {R.id.AccelerometerEngineeringScreen, R.id.RotationVectorEngineeringScreen, R.id.NetworkEngineeringScreen,
                R.id.MagneticEngineeringScreen, R.id.OrientationEngineeringScreen, R.id.GPS_EngineeringScreen, R.id.CallsEngineeringScreen,
                R.id.UpgradeAppButton, R.id.DEV_Action_Button, R.id.FYI_Button},
        listeners = ViewUI_Action.OnClickAsCollection)
private View[] modelViews;
```

I get an Eclipse error saying:

[image]

And Eclipse cannot locate the class containing this field.

So what do you think? Error compiling the class?

Adam.

Comment: Should the `listeners` field have array initializer syntax even for an array of size one? I don't know how forgiving the annotation syntax is...

Comment: Hmmm... looking into it. I've used a constant array... perhaps that is the case? I'll check it out.

Comment: Damn dude, that was one good shoot! but what is funny though, I have all my code rigged with this 'OnClickAsCollection' and only one class shows as error, Post an answer... I'll accept it.

Comment: Are you sure the annotation class is being compiled successfully?

Comment: yes yes... @PlatinumAzure got it the first time :) it all compiles, and I can finally go to sleep cheers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `listeners` field have array initializer syntax even for an array of size one.

Hope that helps :-)